# MEF (.NET) analogue for Java

Tags: java, dependency-injection, mef

I got very used to this clean syntax with MEF in .NET

```
[Export(typeof(ISomething))]
public class Something : ISomething {
}
```

Is there any analogy with annotations in Java? (& corresponding framework).
Any dependency injection containers to be good compatible with?

Answer (score 3):

There are several IoC containers available in Java. The two that comes to my mind are [Spring](http://www.springsource.org) with its [IoC Container](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/reference/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) and [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Injections).

I have mostly worked with [Spring IoC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/reference/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) and find it very nice to work with.

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html) is another good tutorial regarding Spring IoC.

Comment: Thanks. I could eventually find this myself. But voting you up for the help!

Answer (score 2):

From what I could find **to the moment**, I can use [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) with its annotations. There (in [G.G.](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)) they specify default implementer of interface rather then doing export of implementation (as in MEF). E.g.

```
@ImplementedBy(Something.class) 
public interface ISomething {
    ...
}

public class Something implements ISomething {
    ...
}
```

Constructor parameters injections etc are also somewhat possible from documentation.